# What is the simplest way to store a list of numbers in Django model without using third party databases

Tags: django, django-models, django-database

I want to store a list of numbers in Django model without using third party databases like MySQL, PostgreSQL etc. I want a simple approach. I don't think that there is any built-in field like PositiveSmallIntegerField, CharField etc but please do correct me if I am wrong. Is there a way I can use the built-in fields in order to achieve the result or is there a different approach? Please note that I need to add / remove / extract those numbers also.

Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier, I believe it exists already...

```
from django.db.models.fields import CommaSeperatedIntegerField
```

and then you will notice that the system will advise you to use the following:

```
CharField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])
```

and you can import `validate_comma_separated_integer_list` from

```
from django.core.validators import validate_comma_separated_integer_list
```

Comment: This link is taking me to a forms.py file. My question is related to models not forms. Perhaps you have not understood my question.

Comment: My apologies, you're quite right, I'll update my answer

Comment: Check my answer again